# Deploy MS Word Dll with asp.net 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I developed an Asp.net site that reads MS word doc. and do some processing
it worked fine on my pc.
when i deployed it on the web server it gave me this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I Tried almost every solution. but did not work for me
1- I registered the dll on the server using gacutil.exe/i
2- i changed the IIS to be 32 bit appliction... from the pool advanced settings
3- i tried to install this file from Microsoft site
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=18249
4- I tried also this
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

please any help....

Comment: possible duplicate of ['80040154 Class not registered' with interop from ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502040/80040154-class-not-registered-with-interop-from-asp-net) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845841/80040154-class-not-registered-with-word-interop-from-c-sharp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040

Comment: Side note: using Office applications is [not supported in server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) (or any other headless) environments. Use at your own risk.

Comment: what other option do I Have to read doc files on my web server..